# Fingers, hands and wrists specific stretching exercices

Tags: muscle, stretching, tendons, hands, fingers

I am looking for some specific exercices for fingers, hands and wrists to improve the flexibility and not the strength.
This is because I suffered of a bad tendinitis mostly to the flexor tendon of the third and fourth fingers of both hands after playing many years the piano in the wrong way.

At the moment I am looking for totally relaxing and flexibility improving exercices only for hands and wrists. I know some very famous books, like Bob Anderson's "Stretching", but they do not include thorough hand, finger and wrist specific exercices.

I think that what is needed now is to improve the flexibility of muscles and body tissues, especially the membrane of the tendons.

Does someone have some tips? Some suggestion about relevant books or guides?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Having had a problem with a bad tendinitis, you may want to consult a [hand therapist](http://www.assh.org/handcare/About-Hand-Surgery/What-is-a-Hand-Therapist) to get appropriate stretches.  That would be the most direct way to get specific stretches for your hands.  Bob Anderson's "Stretching" will give you other arm and shoulder stretches for a more overall stretch.

Comment: I did not know that there is a specialist in hand therapy. I think that in my situation a customized set of hand stretching exercises would be the best. Thank you very much for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I did different martial arts and as part of the warm up routine we would always do hand/wrist stretching. As it would be a bit difficult to explain them via words, I looked for some videos and found this:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6nS7F8ospQ and several recommended ones on the side of youtube

They explain the stretches in a nice and understanding way. Googling for "martial arts stretch wrist" can give you other examples.

My PT also does something like this at 1:40: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AufR9l265NE.

However, like BackInShapeBuddy I would also recommend to first visit a hand therapist to rule out anything serious and *then* ask someone who knows the excercises to practice them together, so you don't hurt yourself while doing them.

Hope that helped.